# Unit testing a periodic timer via handle_info

Tags: unit-testing, async-await, elixir, gen-server

I have a GenServer which performs a periodic action like so:

```
defmodule Hello
  use GenServer
  def init(_) do
    Process.send_after(self(), :timer, 1000)
    {:ok, %{}}
  end

  def handle_info(:timer, state) do
    # do stuff
    Process.send_after(self(), :timer, 1000)
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to unit test it. My initial idea was to use [mox](https://github.com/plataformatec/mox) to stub the Process.send_after call. This works fine, but then in my unit test, I tried something like this:

```
test "the timer callback does the right thing" do
  MyMock |> expect(:timer, fn -> :ok end)
  {:ok, pid} = start_supervised(Hello, [])
  Process.send(pid, :timer)
  # assert the right thing happens
end
```

However, this doesn't work because `Process.send` is async and doesn't return me anything. How else can I test the `handle_info` callback?

Comment: Is there anything specific that `handle_info(:timer, _)` does which could be used for an assertion? or do you want to only assert that that function is called?

Comment: For my specific scenario, the timer callback calls a function that I control (the module is passed in to the GenServer's state. For my tests, I am passing in a mox namespace.

However, I am also interested in the case where the handle_info changes the state in response to the message, and how one would test that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, like one might spawn an [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Agent.html) from `setup_all` callback and use it in both mock and assertion:

```rb
expect(MyMock, :timer, fn -> Agent.update(MyAgent, & &1 + 1))
...
Process.sleep(1_100)                 # ensure all sent
assert Agent.get(MyAgent, & &1) == 1 # number of calls
```

The probably easiest approach would be to capture IO:

```rb
import ExUnit.CaptureLog
...
test "the timer callback does the right thing" do
  MyMock |> expect(:timer, fn -> IO.inspect(:ok) end)
  {:ok, pid} = start_supervised(Hello, [])

  assert capture_log(fn ->
    Process.send(pid, :timer)
    Process.sleep(1_100)
  end) =~ "ok" 
end
```